# How to change timezone from ISO8601 format in data frame in R?

Tags: r, timezone, iso8601

I have a large dataframe with a column of dates and times in the iso8601 format (YYYY/MM/DDTHH:MM:SSz). I am trying to add a new column and change the time zone. My line of code I am using is below.

```
    df <-cbind(as.POSIXct(df$DateTime, tz = "America/Chicago","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),df)
```

When I use this code, my new column just gives me "NA" values. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: here are the first 5 entries in my data frame when I call it:

```
    df$DateTime[1:5]
```

The output is

```
    df$DateTime[1:5]
    [1] "2018/06/01T05:01:13z" "2018/06/01T05:04:11z" "2018/06/01T05:05:31z" "2018/06/01T05:06:51z" "2018/06/01T05:08:11z"
```

Now, when I use the strptime as was suggested my next line looks like

```
    df1<-as.data.frame(c(strptime(df$DateTime,format='%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%S',tz="America/Chicago"),df))
```

and I get this error

```
   Error in as.POSIXct.default(X[[i]], ...) : 
   do not know how to convert 'X[[i]]' to class “POSIXct”
```

Comment: `strptime(df$DateTime,'%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: If you want better help, please include a sample date, `df$DateTime` means nothing without it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lubridate` package to convert character vector into `datetime` object:

```
df <- data.frame(DateTime_str = c("2018/06/01T05:01:13z",
       "2018/06/01T05:04:11z" ,
       "2018/06/01T05:05:31z",
       "2018/06/01T05:06:51z",
       "2018/06/01T05:08:11z"))

library(lubridate)
df$DateTime <- as_datetime( gsub("z", "", df$DateTime_str), tz = "America/Chicago")
df$DateTime
# [1] "2018-06-01 00:01:13 CDT" "2018-06-01 00:04:11 CDT" "2018-06-01 00:05:31 CDT" "2018-06-01 00:06:51 CDT" "2018-06-01 00:08:11 CDT"
```